# Как убрать отступ во всех блоков одновременно?

Tags: html, css

```css
/*LIST*/
li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 14px;
}
li img {
 position: relative;
 width: 292px;
 height: 258px;
}
.list_city {
 padding-left: 0px;
 position: relative;
}
/*ul li:first-child {
 padding-left: 0px !important;
}*/
ul li:last-child {
 padding-right: 0px !important;
}
img {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 0;
}
ul li {
 position: relative;
 left: -14px;
}
.establishments {
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #fff;
 left: 25px;
 bottom: 55px;
}
.hotels, .hostels, .houseroom {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.hotels a, .hostels a, .houseroom a {
 color: red;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.city_name {
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 text-align: left;
 left: 25px;
 top: 79px;
 font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="city_block">
  <ul class="list_city">
    <li>
      <img src="https://www.drinkpreneur.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/www.drinkpreneur.com-dubai-37075265-1494255242-imagegallerylightboxlarge.jpg">
        <span class="city_name">Dubai</span>
        <div class="establishments">
          <div class="hotels"><a href="#">260 отелей</a></div>
          <div class="hostels"><a href="#">60 хостели</a></div>
          <div class="houseroom"><a href="#">250 дома</a></div>
        </div> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://www.lacity.org/sites/g/files/wph781/f/styles/tiled_homepage_blog/public/bigstock-Los-Angeles-5909078.jpg?itok=Pu2dewLz">
      <span class="city_name">Los Angeles</span>
      <div class="establishments">
        <div class="hotels"><a href="#">260 отелей</a></div>
        <div class="hostels"><a href="#">60 хостели</a></div>
      </div> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://cdn.flixbus.de/city_description_images/amsterdam-nightlife.jpg">
   <span class="city_name">Amsterdam</span>
   <div class="establishments">
     <div class="hotels">
            <a href="#">260 отелей</a>
          </div>
     <div class="hostels">
            <a href="#">60 хостели</a>
          </div>
   </div>
    </li>
        <li>
      <img src="https://cdn.londonandpartners.com/visit/general-london/areas/westminster-st-james/60262-640x360-parliament-bridge-640.jpg">
   <span class="city_name">London</span>
   <div class="establishments">
     <div class="hotels">
            <a href="#">260 отелей</a>
          </div>
     <div class="hostels">
            <a href="#">60 хостели</a>
          </div>
   </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Всем привет.Такая проблема обратите внимания есть 4 блока с картинками.Внутри первого блока есть 4 подблока имя страны и 3 учреждений отель хостел также дома а вот в остальных 3 блоках нету 3 учреждений у них по каждому 2 блока отель и хостель и как видите там есть вверхний отступ.Помогите как его убрать ?Чтобы даже когда был 1 блок учреждений он был под именем страны.Но чтобы у всех элементов был 1 класс как я написал при добавлении индивидуальных классов каждому элементу решить этот вопрос я могу а мне нужно чтобы у всех блоков учреждений был 1 обший класс.

Comment: позиционируйте весь текстовый блок, а не по отдельности

Comment: позиционировал убрал все элементы с классами hotels hostels houserooms и добавил обший класс all_establishment тот же эффект к сожалению

Comment: .establishments {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #fff;
    left: 25px;
    top: 120px;
}

Comment: @Павел спасибо я тоже нашел данное решение и помогло

Comment: пример - https://jsfiddle.net/m68r0xdz/

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо вам решение уже нашлось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ был прост проста заменить `bottom` на `top` в классе `establishments` top:116px` и все